# How to draw a circle with matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, geometry

I'm trying to draw a circle using pyplot. However, in the plot is looks like an ellipse.

The variable r can have any value.

```
theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
   
r= r/2

x = r*np.cos(theta)
y = r*np.sin(theta)
   
plt.plot(x,y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `pyplot.axis('equal')` method ([documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axis.html?highlight=pyplot%20axis#matplotlib.pyplot.axis)). This will tell matplotlib to automatically keep the x and y axis scaling equal and will work even if you change the axis limits:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
r= 2
x = r*np.cos(theta)
y = r*np.sin(theta)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot of a circle that looks circular]

As you can see, this causes circles to be circles even if the x and y axis have different limits. It also allows for autoscaling if additional items are added to the plot and it will maintain the aspect ratio when the plot area is modified by adding axis labels or a plot title.

There are additional examples of this in the Matplotlib documentation: [Axis Equal Demo](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/axis_equal_demo.html).

Another option is to use `pyplot.axis('scaled')`, which changes the dimensions of the plot box to make the axis scaling equal. The difference is that this option will block further autoscaling after it has been set.

For example, with 'scaled' axes, matplotlib will respect the values you specify for the x- and y-axis limits:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
r= 2
x = r*np.cos(theta)
y = r*np.sin(theta)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.axis('scaled')
plt.ylim(-3, 3)
plt.xlim(-3, 3)
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot of circle with equal limits on the x and y axes]

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a way to have (-3 to 3) on the y axis as well.
I mean the same x and y axis.

Comment: @proxima - this is what the 'scaled' option does. Please see my updated answer for an example.

Comment: Is there a way to autoscale both axes?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want, but it will autoscale if you don't set the limits manually. I did that because you asked for the range to be (-3 to 3) on both axis. Take a look at the demo that I linked to see other examples.

Comment: for instance, I have a circle 250x250 with plt.axis('equal'), but the figure or the box is not square it's more like x=500 and y=250, but the circle is not stretched. I can't have to box auto scale with the same x and y.

Comment: I have to change the limits If I draw something smaller or bigger.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. Most likely the aspect ratio of your figure is not equal. Setting the figsize to equal arguments should fix that

```
theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
r= r/2
x = r*np.cos(theta)
y = r*np.sin(theta)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.plot(x,y)
```

[image: figure of circle]